# Why is email so slow?

Tags: email

I setup a new vps.net server.

I tried to send mail from PHP. It would not.

I installed sendmail `apt-get install sendmail`.

It now sends mail, but the server lags for about a minute before sending an email.

Not sure why this could be?

Comment: I provided the log to community, and it made a quick look on my problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have a look at `/var/log/mail.err` and `/var/log/mail.log` for error output from sendmail, that might shed some light on the problem.

From your description though I'd hazard a guess that the server is stalling trying to resolve DNS - have you got nameservers correctly configured in `/etc/resolv.conf`?

Comment: What exactly do I put inside the /etc/resolv.conf file? the IP of my server? or domain name? or dns nameserver? Thanks.

Comment: I think this is the issue, the log says unable to qualify domain name. I do not know how to setup resolv.conf, I have a different question pending for that answer.

Comment: Actually I needed to add the domains to the `/etc/hosts` file.

Comment: @John: No, you needed to **fix DNS**. `/etc/hosts` is only a temporary workaround.

Comment: @grawity, I am so confused. I asked this question http://serverfault.com/questions/233995/ and thats what I was told.

Comment: @John: Nevermind, then – I thought you were adding the addresses of _remote_ servers.