# How to configure multi domain nameservers in resolv.conf?

Tags: nameserver, domain, resolv.conf

I have a server that has 2 domains pointing to it `domain1.com` and `domain2.com`.

They both use the same name servers: `dns1.vps.net` and `dns2.vps.net`.

When I run `cat resolv.conf`

This is its contents:

```
# Automatically generated by OnApp (2.0.rc5.i)    
domain
nameserver 8.8.8.8
nameserver 8.8.4.4
```

What should actually be in here?

#### EDIT

I asked [this question](https://serverfault.com/questions/233977/why-is-email-so-slow)

They told me to look at my `/var/log/mail.log` and that it was probably because my resolv.conf was not configured right.

In the log it says:

> Feb 10 18:01:02 my-domain sm-msp-queue[7933]: unable to qualify my own domain name (my-domain) -- using short name

I think this is why the server lags for about 60 seconds every time I try to send email from PHP.

Comment: What problem do you have? The IPs listed in your resolv.conf are google's public DNS servers, I don't see nothing wrong there. But I still don't get your problem/question ?

Comment: I see no problem with the contents of your `resolv.conf` file, can you rephrase your question in the form of "X does not work, how can I fix it?" :-)

Comment: @rems @voretaq7 I edited my question, is it better now?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check that you have a fully qualified name (dev-kranichs.domain.something) for 127.0.0.1 in your /etc/hosts.

You should have a line looking similar to

```
127.0.0.1   dev-kranichs.domain.something   dev-kranichs


127.0.0.1   dev-kranichs.local   dev-kranichs
```

could be enough.

Comment: I have to lines in my hosts file `127.0.0.1 localhost` and `216.119.xxx.xxx dev-kranichs dev-kranichs`. (those x's are actually numbers) The domain is actually `dev-kranichs.com` is that what you meant by .domain.something? Also my other domain `dev-other.com` is not in there at all, shouldn't it be too? Thanks!!

Comment: I added both domains to 127.0.0.1 and 216.119.xxx.xxx with and without `.com` and I restarted apache. It no longer lags when I send the email. However, I did get this error when I restarted: ` Could not reliably determine the server's fully qualified domain name, using 127.0.0.1 for ServerName` Do not know what that means.

Answer (score 0):

Those are DNS server IPs used by your server to resolve DNS names as much as I know.